# Introduction to Manifolds, Loring W. Tu page 225

Tags: manifolds

$$\ ϕ_{t*}\biggl(\frac∂
{∂x^j}\bigg|_
p \biggr)
= \sum_i
\frac{∂ϕ^i}
{∂x^j} (t, p) \frac∂
{∂x^i}\bigg|_{
ϕ_t(p)}$$
Thus, if $\ Y = ∑b^j\frac∂{∂x^j}$
, then
$$\ ϕ_{−t∗}
Y_{ϕ_t(p)}
= \sum_j
b_j
(ϕ(t, p))ϕ_{−t∗}
\biggl(\frac{∂}{∂x^j}\bigg|_{ϕ_t(p)}\biggr)= \sum_{i, j}
b_j
(ϕ(t, p))\frac{∂ϕ^i}{∂x^j} (−t, "p") \frac∂{∂x^i}\bigg|_p $$

Shouldn't the "p" part be $\ \phi_t(p) $ instead of p?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Yes, it should. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. Good catch!